# Update react-redux store from a loop

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a simple array in my store from which a grid of react components is rendered. Say my grid is:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

My store is: `{selected: 0, array: {1,2,3,4,5,6}}`

If I update my store property "selected" to 2 then the grid shows:

```
1 _ 3
4 5 6
```

I want to be able to iterate that "_" across my array by updating my store. However, when I do this in a for loop in react, I only get the end result. I know this happens because react doesn't immediately render the updated state but rather queues the updates. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Your assumption might be wrong, please share more code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can force your component to update with the [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook.

The first argument is a callback function, the second argument is an array of variables which will force a re-render when any of these dependency variables change.

I can't really go into details of implementation without seeing more of your code but it's pretty easy to follow the documentation from React.